# Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' from importing torch_geometric

Tags: pytorch, python-import, importerror, bad-alloc, pytorch-geometric

I am writing in python and getting the error:

"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'.
what():  std::bad_alloc.
Aborted (core dumped)"

After lots of debugging, I found out the source of the issue is:

```
import torch_geometric
```

I even created a file with just this line of code, and I still get the error.
I am running in a conda environment (4.10.3)
I made sure that I installed torch_geometric while I was in the conda environment. I tried deleting and reinstalling, but this did not work.
I also tried deleting and reinstalling torch/cuda.
I googled the error, but only seemed to come up with issues in data allocation, but I'm not sure how this would be an issue, since I am just importing torch_geometric.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

This problem is because of mismatched versions of pytorch.
The current pytorch being used is 1.11.0, but when scatter and sparse were installed installed scatter and sparse, 1.10.1 were used:

- pip install torch-scatter -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.10.1+cu113.html.
- pip install torch-sparse -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.10.1+cu113.html

So,torch-1.10.1 was used to install scatter and sparse, but torch-1.11.0 was the true version.

Simply doing:

- pip uninstall torch-scatter
- pip uninstall torch-sparse
- pip install torch-scatter -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.11.0+cu113.html.
- pip install torch-sparse -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.11.0+cu113.html

Resolves the issue.

Comment: works for torch_scatter but `import torch_sparse` results in `OSError: libtorch_cuda_cu.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Comment: I had a different torch version, that was all.

Comment: Yes, you just need to make sure torch versions match.

Comment: I encountered the same behavior by mixing conda-forge with other conda channels. The docs for [pyg](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/installation.html) and [torch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) specify other channels, not conda-forge.